# Running a mono program from command line in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mono

Believe me, I have tried searching for this, but all the posts I have seen on mono stops at installation. I have a hello world C# program that I want to execute from the command line - how do I do that?

In addition, I want to run only command line programs in mono. What mono packages should I install (I'm on Ubuntu) for me to just be able to do that?

Answer (score 2):

`mono helloworld.exe`, or, if you have the binfmt handler installed, just `./helloworld.exe` (make sure you got execute permissions). Note that the [Mono Basics](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_Basics) on the official website has a tutorial for beginners.

What packages to install depends on what libraries the programs you want to run need. Bare minimum would be `mono-runtime` (which will pull in some dependencies automatically). You can't go wrong with `mono-complete`, though ;)